# SAP: create a new product based on existing ones

Tags: grocery-crud

I am sure that this question already exists but as I am not familiar to SAP development (am an IT auditor) I can't really do a decent search. So I apologize in advance.

We are introducing a new product in our grocery store: a sandwich. The ingredients are : certain amount of bread, rumsteak and cheese.
These base products are already in the SAP. 
Can you please tell me how should I create a new product called "sandwich" which will be connected to my basic products? So when I sell or make a sandwich it is taken into account and has an impact on the quantity of bread and cheese etc.?

Thank you so so so much for your help, stackoverflow!

Comment: Sorry but Stack Overflow is a help site about programming questions. You can probably ask this question in the SAP forum corresponding to the SAP software you are talking about.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the stock of your base ingredients to be reduced when your product is sold, you can use a sales BOM (Bill of materials). If you want to produce your product using your base ingredients and then store the final product in your warehouse, you'd create a production BOM and create production orders.

This is of course a very, very, very (repeat about 20 times) short summary of the necessary customizing. Creating a sales BOM is relatively easy, but doesn't give you the ability to track your product stock. Production orders require some additional customization in module PP (maybe even PP-PI, depending on your scenario) and of course need someone to create production orders, create the products, then confirm the production orders.